# Dynamically specifying number of outputs

Tags: matlab

[numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is [ind2sub](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) like

```matlab
[i1, i2, ..., i<ndims(x)>] = ind2sub(size(x), find(x > 0));
```

except `np.where` returns a tuple of `i1`, `i2`, ..., which themselves are arrays (so we can just do `out = np.where()`).

The idea is, `np.where` doesn't need to worry about knowing `ndims(x)`. Is there a way to do the same with MATLAB? I was thinking below:

```matlab
out = cell(1, ndims(x));
out{:} = ind2sub(size(x), find(x > 0));  % DOESN'T WORK
```

More generally: can we force a `nargout` upon a MATLAB function programmatically, without typing out `nargout` number of variables?

---

My current port of `np.where` would simply use `switch ndims(x)` in a custom function:

```matlab
function out = np_where(bools, sz)
    switch numel(sz)
        case 1
            i1 = ind2sub(sz, bools);
            out = {i1};
        case 2
            [i1, i2] = ind2sub(sz, bools);
            out = {i1, i2};
        % ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use brackets around your [comma-separated list](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) which is formed when you say `out{:}`.

```matlab
x = randi([-1 1],2,2,2,2);
out = cell(1, ndims(x));
[out{:}] = ind2sub(size(x), find(x > 0));
```